# Query in all members of a list JSONField

Tags: django-models, django-orm, django-jsonfield, jsonfield

In django 4.2 I have a model with an attribute specialties.

it is a JSONField and it is a list like this:

```
Practitioner.objects.create(
     name="Aldridge, Elizabeth Jane",
     specialties = [
    {
        "type": "CFPC Specialist",
        "issued_on": "Effective:18 May 2009",
        "specialty": "Family Medicine"
    },
    {
        "type": "RCPSC Specialist",
        "issued_on": "Effective:30 Jun 2019",
        "specialty": "Anesthesiology"
    }
]
```

it may have 0 member or more than 2 members.

this is my query:

```
practitioners = Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__0__specialty = "Anesthesiology")
```

i want to search in all members of specialties not in 0th one.

I have tested this incorrect queries:

```
practitioners = Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__each__specialty = "Anesthesiology")

practitioners = Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__any__specialty = "Anesthesiology")

practitioners = Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__all__specialty = "Anesthesiology")
```

i did not find any solution in django documentations.

Comment: Usually if data is structured, it makes not much sense to store that as a JSON blob in a *relational* database, because it makes querying less expressive and less efficient as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise *not* to use a [**`JSONField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField). In relational databases, `JSONField`s nearly always break [*first normal form* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and the case that you want to search over all records actually proves that it breaks first normal form: all columns should be treated as *atomic* values in the sense that you don't want to look at substructures. But here you clearly do that.

Especially since the data is structured, there is no reason to use a `JSONField`, use an extra model with a [**`ForeignKey`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

```
class Practitioner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)


class Specialty(models.Model):
    practicioner = models.ForeignKey(
        Practitioner, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='specialties'
    )
    issued_on = models.DateField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    specialty = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

then we query with:

```
Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__specialty='Anesthesiology')
```

Since the values like `type` and `specialty` seem to be categorical, you might even want to make extra models for these, and add `ForeignKey`s from `Specialty` to these extra models. This will also reduce the size of the database, make querying more efficient, but perhaps the main reason why normal forms were introduced in the first place: if you need to update the name of a `specialty`, that is quite easy.

Comment: thanks ! this is a good way. but not my desired.

Comment: @HosseinSayyedmousavi: well using a JSON field violates in this case first normal form, which means it is not well-suited for *relational database design*: it will result in slow queries, inefficient disk usage, but probably imho the most important part: make updating a lot more troublesome :). That is why they created database normalization forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

```
practitioners = Practitioner.objects.filter(specialties__contains = [{"specialty":"Anesthesiology"}])
```